# C# Async object transmission (Sockets?)

Tags: c#, tcp, asyncsocket

I am trying to figure out what the best way to approach Async object transmission.

What I want to do is have multiple instances of the same application open across a network connection (5-10 clients) that connect to one server, and when one of the applications updates its data, I need to transmit that update to all the other instances.

The update objects will be similar to this:

```
public class UpdateData
{
    public double Angle { get; set; }
    public double Azimuth { get; set; }
    public Point Position { get; set; }
    public Guid ObjectGuid { get; set; }
}
```

The data won't be very big, but objects of this type will be transmitted about 10-50 times per second from each client to all the other clients.

What is the best way to handle this kind of data transmission?

What I was thinking is have a server object listen and accept connections using something similar to this:

```
    private void BtConnectClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int port;

        if (!int.TryParse(tbPort.Text, out port))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid port into the textbox");
            tbPort.Text = "";
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            _listener.Start();

            _listener.BeginAcceptSocket(OnClientConnect, _listener);

        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }

    }

    public void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {
            var s = _listener.EndAcceptSocket(asyn);

            _clients.Add(s);  // List<Socket> object
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
    }
```

But how should the server handle the data transmission?

I know I should be trying to receive data from all of the sockets in `_clients` and once I receive data, I need to forward it onto all the other sockets in `_clinets`, but how should I do this?  How and where should I detect when a client has terminated its connection?

Also, the clients should be listening for data to be received from the server as well as sending data to the server. Can I handle all of that with one socket or should I use 2?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I wonder... do you have to do this yourself? There are a number of message buses pre-rolled. Heck, you could use redis for this pretty trivially (pub/sub)...

Comment: I don't have to do it myself.  I'm not entirely familiary 'redis', could you elaborate?

Comment: redis is *strictly speaking* a (free) cache server, but it includes pub/sub. Your listeners issue a SUBSCRIBE to some named channel, and the publisher issues a PUBLISH to that channel: thus, whatever chunk of data you sent is distributed to all listeners. You can find c# bindings easily enough, or I have a fully async one here that I want to get Jeff to let me release as a mini-project...

Comment: See also: http://redis.io/commands#pubsub

Comment: I've just had the go-ahead to release my async redis bindings to the community; I will try to add them later today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would leave this to a message-bus/service-bus, or anything else with pub/sub. My preference would be redis: http://redis.io/commands#pubsub

Re the object, I would use protobuf-net, simply because I know it will produce tiny binary for the above message. Sending (PUBLISH) a BLOB to a named redis channel will cause it to be distributed to all listeners on that channel.

Comment: Ok, this is definitely the easy way to do things.  Thanks!